# Monogame - Rotate Sprite around centre of screen and itself

Tags: rotation, xna, sprite, monogame

I have a problem and although I serached everywhere I couldn't find a solution.

I have a stacked sprite and I'm rotating this sprite around the center of the screen. So I iterate over a list of sprites (stacked) and increase the y-coordinate by 2 every loop (rotation is increased step by step by 0.01f outside of the loop):

```
            foreach(var s in stacked)
            {

                Vector2 origin = new Vector2(Basic.width / 2, Basic.height / 2);
                Rectangle newPosition = new Rectangle(position.X, position.Y - y, position.Width, position.Height);
                float angle = 0f;

                Matrix transform = Matrix.CreateTranslation(-origin.X, -origin.Y, 0f) *
                                   Matrix.CreateRotationZ(rotation) *
                                   Matrix.CreateTranslation(origin.X, origin.Y, 0f);

                Vector2 pos = new Vector2(newPosition.X, newPosition.Y);
                pos = Vector2.Transform(pos, transform);
                newPosition.X = (int)pos.X;
                newPosition.Y = (int)pos.Y;
                angle += rotation;

                s.Draw(newPosition, origin, angle, Color.White);

                y += 2;
            }
```

This works fine. But now my problem. I want not only to rotate the sprite around the center of the screen but also around itself. How to achieve this? I can only set one origin and one rotation per Draw. I would like to rotate the sprite around the origin 'Basic.width / 2, Basic.height / 2' and while it rotates, around 'position.Width / 2, position.Height / 2'. With different rotation speed each. How is this possible?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the relationship between `y` and `stacked`? fixed offset per `s`? What is `position`?  Ask yourself what are your positional rotational origin chains, then tell me.  Which of the chains(angles) do you want your sprite to follow?

Comment: You are confusing positional rotation about a fixed point (or more, could be extended from the end with another rotator...)  with sprite draw rotation, they may or may not be related. A Farris wheel carriage always points down.

Comment: y is increased bei 2 in my loop and added to position.Y. Position is the position of my current tile.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear:

When using `SpriteBatch.Draw()` with origin and angle, there is only **one** rotation: the final angle of the sprite.

The other rotations are positional offsets.

The origin in the `Draw()` call is a translation, rotation, translate back.  Your transform matrix shows this quite well:

```
Matrix transform = Matrix.CreateTranslation(-origin.X, -origin.Y, 0f) *
                                   Matrix.CreateRotationZ(rotation) *
                                   Matrix.CreateTranslation(origin.X, origin.Y, 0f);
```

---

```
//Class level variables:
float ScreenRotation, ScreenRotationSpeed;
float ObjectRotation, ObjectRotationSpeed;
Vector2 ScreenOrigin, SpriteOrigin;
// ...

// In constructor and resize events:
  ScreenOrigin = new Vector2(Basic.width <<1, Basic.height <<1); 
// shifts are faster for `int` type. If "Basic.width" is `float`:
//ScreenOrigin = new Vector2(Basic.width, Basic.height) * 0.5f; 


// In Update():
  ScreenRotation += ScreenRotationSpeed; // * gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Seconds; // for FPS invariant speed where speed = 60 * single frame speed
  ObjectRotation+= ObjectRotationSpeed;

//Calculate the screen center rotation once per step
  Matrix baseTransform = Matrix.CreateTranslation(-ScreenOrigin.X, -ScreenOrigin.Y, 0f) *
  Matrix.CreateRotationZ(ScreenRotation) *
  Matrix.CreateTranslation(ScreenOrigin.X, ScreenOrigin.Y, 0f);

// In Draw() at the start of your code snippet posted:

// moved outside of the loop for a translationally invariant vertical y interpretation
// or move it inside the loop and apply -y to position.Y for an elliptical effect

  Vector2  ObjectOrigin = new Vector2(position.X, position.Y);
  Matrix transform = baseTransform *
  Matrix.CreateTranslation(-ObjectOrigin.X, -ObjectOrigin.Y, 0f) *
  Matrix.CreateRotationZ(ObjectRotation) *
  Matrix.CreateTranslation(ObjectOrigin.X, ObjectOrigin.Y, 0f);


foreach(var s in stacked)
{
  Vector2 pos = new Vector2(ObjectOrigin.X, ObjectOrigin.Y - y);
  pos = Vector2.Transform(pos, transform);
  float DrawAngle = ObjectRotation;
// or float DrawAngle = ScreenRotation;
// or float DrawAngle = ScreenRotation + ObjectRotation;
// or float DrawAngle = 0;
  s.Draw(pos, SpriteOrigin, DrawAngle, Color.White);
}
```

I suggest moving the `Draw()` parameter away from `destinationRectangle` and use the `Vector2 position` directly with scaling. Rotations within square rectangles can differ up to `SQRT(2)` in aspect ratio, i.e. stretching/squashing. Using `Vector2` incurs a cost of higher collision complexity.

I am sorry for the `or`s, but without complete knowledge of the problem...YMMV

In my 2D projects, I use the vector form of polar coordinates.
The `Matrix` class requires more calculations than the polar equivalents in 2D. Matrix operates in 3D, wasting cycles calculating Z components.

With normalized direction vectors (cos t,sin t) and a radius(vector length),in many cases I use `Vector2.LengthSquared()` to avoid the square root when possible.

---

The only time I have used Matrices in 2D is display projection matrix(entire SpriteBatch) and Mouse and TouchScreen input deprojection(times the inverse of the projection matrix)